# Why doesn't this function run correctly on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

A gentleman helped get the function to sum the table's input fields, which works great here. However, in my situation, the function runs on page load, the `else{}` runs, but there is no output into the destination input fields, nor does this show any error in the console log. I thought that you might have run into a similar situation and could have the answer to that...?

**strong text**
The script gets the data from server and builds the page, including the table with about 11 columns containing these input field and multiple rows. If I change any of the columns' values, the function sums that row's total and outputs the result correctly, but not on load.
This is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73888920/11832197)

```js
function sum_row_qty(el) {
  let rowTotal = 0
  if (el) {
    let parent = el.closest("tr")
    parent.querySelectorAll('.size_qty').forEach(function(e) {
      rowTotal += parseFloat(e.value)
    })
    parent.querySelector('.qty').value = rowTotal
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows > tr > td:first-child input").forEach(sum_row_qty);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => sum_row_qty());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="2" onchange="sum_row_qty(this)"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="2" onchange="sum_row_qty(this)"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="6" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input class="size_qty" type="number" min="0" name="numberInputs" value="3" onchange="sum_row_qty(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" readonly="true"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried waiting for the page to be ready, but still:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    sum_row_qty();
});
```

Thank you!

Thank you!

Comment: because a `load` event can come from different parts of the loading of your page, such as simply an image or an icon, or any link in the `<head>` etc... while the page is not yet fully loaded.

Comment: `a load event can come from different parts of the loading of your page` - no *The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images* - the documentation clearly states that *All events named load will **not** propagate to Window* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: your code correctly sets the third column to the sum of the first two on window load - I don't see the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-an-html-file